# append a Child with insertBefore tool

Tags: javascript

I am trying to append a div element to another element (the 'contenedor' div element) in this code that will eventually have an audio. The thing is that the console keeps telling me that the child i am trying to parent its not a child of the node. Also, sooner, when i create the audio element, would I have to have any consideration with the insert before tool?

```js
let section = document.querySelector('seccion');
let container = document.querySelector('container');

let optionButtons = document.querySelector('option-buttons')
let participanteUno = document.getElementById('participante1')
let participanteDos = document.getElementById('participante2');


const historia1 = function() {
    alert('Has recibido un nuevo correo \n ¿Deseas leerlo?')
    let base1 = document.getElementById('base');
    base1.innerHTML = '<p> EHola, \n tengo el agrado de comunicarme contigo para contarte que he encontrado tus datos en la cartera de una chica</p>'
    

let contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor');
let borrarParticipanteUno = document.getElementById('option-buttons').removeChild(participanteUno) 
let borrarParticipanteDos = document.getElementById('option-buttons').removeChild(participanteDos);
let botonTerminarJuego = document.createElement('button')
botonTerminarJuego.setAttribute('id', 'salir')
    botonTerminarJuego.innerText = 'Salir'
let optionButtons = document.getElementById('option-buttons').appendChild(botonTerminarJuego)
document.getElementById('salir').addEventListener('click', salir, true)
let modEstiloSalir = document.getElementById('salir').style.color = 'black'
let botonSiguiente = document.createElement('button')
botonSiguiente.setAttribute('id', 'siguiente')
botonSiguiente.innerText = 'Siguiente'
optionButtons = document.getElementById('option-buttons').appendChild(botonSiguiente)
document.getElementById('siguiente').addEventListener('click', siguiente, true)
let modEstiloSiguiente = document.getElementById('siguiente').style.color = 'black'

let btnGrid = document.getElementById('option-buttons')
btnGrid.style.border = '1px'
btnGrid.style.padding = '10px'

}


const esteban1 = participanteUno.addEventListener('click', historia1, true);

//creating a 'next' button event and adding a div 
const siguiente = function() {
const base = document.getElementById('base');
base.innerHTML = `<H2>REPRODUCIENDO...</H2>`;
let audioA = document.createElement('div')
audioA.setAttribute('id', 'audioA')
let parentDiv = document.getElementById('contenedor').parentNode
let btnGrid = document.getElementById('base')
parentDiv.insertBefore(audioA, btnGrid)


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>text Adventure</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=DotGothic16&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon"> 
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section>
    <head>
    <div id="titulo">
        <h1>Nombre de la obra</h1>
    </div>
</head>
</section>  
</head>
<body>
    <section id="seccion">    
    <div id="contenedor" class="container">
        <div id="base">
            <p id="text">Intrucciones: <br> Estás entrando a una obra que requiere de toda tu atención, ya que serás parte de la historia. Para adentrarte a ella deberás hacer uso del botón 'Siguiente' que te mostrará las indicaciones y te ayudará a seguir con la historia. Además, podrás observar el botón 'Terminar juego'; al presionarlo podrás salir de este. Te recomendamos que lo uses en caso de  una emergencias (aburrimiento, fatiga, etc.) siempre y cuando hayas acordado con el participante frente a ti previamenente. <br> Lo primero que deberás hacer es escoger qué participante quisieras interpretar (acuerdalo con la persona frente a tí). Una vez hecho esto, presiona el participante que escogiste y podrás empezar con la historia. <br> Ahora sí, que comience la función... </p>
        </div>
        <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button id='participante1' class="btn">Participante 1</button>  
        <button id='participante2' class="btn">Participante 2</button>            
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>    
    <script type='text/javascript' src="app.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#base` element is child of `#contenedor` and not `#seccion` therefore you can't insert before non-existing child.